# Как определит RadioSelect для ModelForm в Django?

Tags: html, python, django

Я создаю приложение для сбора обратной связи от пользователей на django. Вопрос заключается в том, как связать модель с html-формой, используя django widgets и ModelForm?

Моя модель:
**models.py**

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .forms import FeedbackForm

class Survey(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = FeedbackForm()
        return render(request, 'form/index.html', context={'form': form)
```

Форма django:
**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Feedback


class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ['rate']

        widgets = {
            'rate': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'name': 'rating'}}
```

Часть html-формы:
**index.html**

```
<h1 class="form-header">Насколько вероятно Вы порекомендуете инструмент?</h1>
        <div class="rating-wrapper">

            <label class="radio-container">1
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
                <span class="radio-checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="radio-container">2
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
                <span class="radio-checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="radio-container">3
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
                <span class="radio-checkmark"></span>
            </label>

       </div>
```

Каким образом я могу определить атрибуты для виджета, чтобы генерировался такой же html-шаблон? И соответственно, каким образом я могу итерироваться по полю rate в html-шаблоне, чтобы генерировалось, например, 10 радиокнопок? Т.е., получается что при выборе определенной радиокнопки её значение должно записываться в поле rate модели Feedback.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Точно не уверен, но попробуйте: `{% for radio in FeedbackForm.rate %} <div class="myradio"> {{ radio }} </div> {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы можно было итерироваться по полю rate надо добавить атрибут choices в конструктор класса RadioSelect и определить возможные варианты выбора, т.е. форма будут выглядеть следующим образом:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Feedback


class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ['rate']
        choices = ((1, 1), (2, 2),)

        widgets = {'rate': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'name': 'rating'}, choices=choices)}
```

**В html-шаблоне:**

```
<h1 class="form-header">Насколько вероятно Вы порекомендуете инструмент </h1>
    <div class="rating-wrapper">
        {% for radio in form.rate %}
          <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}" class="rating-wrapper">
            {{ radio.choice_label }}
            {{ radio.tag }}
            <span class="radio-checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        {% endfor %}
   </div>
```